# how to retrieve the updated data from the gridbox and update it in the database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

My Code actually returns the data which it has previously got from database but am unable to get the updated data from the gridcontrol.

This is my Default.aspx where designing has been done of gridview.

```
 <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"
    onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowInsertButton="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Id" Text='<%# Bind("id")%>' runat="server">  </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_name" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="address">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_address" Text='<%# Bind("address")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_address" Text='<%# Bind("address")%>'    runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
   <asp:Label ID="lbl_msg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </asp:Content>



 My.cs File
```

My Code is row updating method in the below class.
I have used entity framework as a method for having manipulations in the data base.

```
 using System; 
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
     using DatabaseModel;

   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
   DatabaseEntities obj;

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   obj = new DatabaseEntities();
   GridView1.DataSource = obj.Records.ToList();
  GridView1.DataBind();
  }
  string data;

  protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {

  }

  protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
   GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
   TextBox name = row.FindControl("txt_name") as TextBox;
  TextBox address = row.FindControl("txt_address") as TextBox;
  Label id = row.FindControl("lbl_Id") as Label;
  int no = int.Parse(id.Text);
   Record rec = obj.Records.First(x => x.Id == no);
  rec.Name = name.Text;
  rec.Address = address.Text;
   obj.SaveChanges();
  data = name.Text;
   lbl_msg.Text = name.Text;
  }

  protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
  {
  }

 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
  }
 }
```

Comment: There's a slight difference between `asp.net`, `asp.net-mvc` and `asp-classic`. Please use those tags appropriately when asking a question on StackOverflow to identify your target platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problem in linq query, use lambda expression and use this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do not rebind the data on postback
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        obj = new DatabaseEntities();
        GridView1.DataSource = obj.Records.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because data is rebound before `GridView1_RowUpdating` is triggered. Try to change the `Page_Load` method like this:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do not rebind the data on postback
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        obj = new DatabaseEntities();
        GridView1.DataSource = obj.Records.ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it.  
It indeed id working, but showing null exception in the LINQ Query

Comment: You're right, I see it now. The obj variable is instantiated only on postback. Just move "obj = new DatabaseEntities();" line above the if statement.